# Can't preview custom post - Redirected to home page

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, permalinks, wp-admin

When I click on preview in custom post types I get redirected to home page.
But when I visit or view the page that have all the Custom posts in I can see all of them.

I cant figure out what or why.

**NOTE**
I allready tried all the Settings -> Permalinks options.

**Update #1 CTP registration**

```
function register_cpt_cars() {
    $labels = array( 
        'name' => _x( 'Cars', 'cars' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'Cars', 'cars' ),
        'add_new' => _x( 'Add new', 'cars' ),
        'add_new_item' => _x( 'Add new Car', 'cars' ),
        'edit_item' => _x( 'Edit Cars', 'cars' ),
        'new_item' => _x( 'New Car', 'cars' ),
        'view_item' => _x( 'Show cars', 'cars' ),
        'search_items' => _x( 'Search Car', 'cars' ),
        'not_found' => _x( 'No car found', 'cars' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => _x( 'No cars found in the trash', 'cars' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => _x( 'Parent cars:', 'cars' ),
        'menu_name' => _x( 'Cars', 'cars' ),
    );

    $args = array( 
        'labels' => $labels,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'description' => 'New Cars',
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail' ),
        'taxonomies' => array( 'category'),
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'menu_position' => 20,
        'menu_icon' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/img/icons/53-house.png',
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'can_export' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post'
    );

    register_post_type( 'cars', $args );
}
```

**Update #2**

Tried removing **rewrite** and **capability**_type from CTP registrations.
Still dont work. I get to my homepage but the URL changes.

Comment: How about showing us your CPT registration code?

Comment: @kaiser - Sorry my bad, question updated with CTP code.

Comment: Remove `capability_type` and `rewrite`. Then try again. Additional info: Remove everything that is already [a default value](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) from core. Sidenote: We don't understand Viking... so better use English in **all cases** so later readers understand your question as well...

Comment: @kaiser - Ok , translated. I tried as you suggested but it didnt work. I still see the home page but the url has changed. Any more suggestions on that one ?

Comment: Please always go back and update your question with what you've tried. So if you removed all the default values, then please show us what is left now. You asked already 17 questions - you should know better. Thanks.

Comment: Done, updated!- @kaiser

Comment: Sorry, but you didn't read what I linked you. 90% of your arguments are either default or inherited. And you didn't even update your code. You just added a note below. I'll stop here.